# How to replace everything between but only until the first occurrence of the end string?

Tags: string, sed

I have to replace everything between two strings in a file but only until the first occurrence of the second string.

Here is a sample line of file content,

```
AuthorSessionId&#xd;&#xa;, CONVERT_TZ&#x28;CreatedAt,&#x22;&#x24;&#x7b;DatabaseTimezone&#x7d;&#x22;,&#x22;&#x24;&#x7b;ApplicationTimezone&#x7d;&#x22;&#x29; AS CreatedAt&#xd;&#xa;FROM PlayerPhoneArchive &#xd;&#xa;WHERE RevisionDate BETWEEN &#x3f; AND &#x3f;&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;&#xa;&#x29; AS PH &#xd;&#xa;
```

In this, I wanted to replace everything starts from `CONVERT_TZ` until before the first of `&#xd;&#xa;` with `CreatedAt&#xd;&#xa;`.

The final output should be,

```
AuthorSessionId&#xd;&#xa;, CreatedAt&#xd;&#xa;FROM PlayerPhoneArchive &#xd;&#xa;WHERE RevisionDate BETWEEN &#x3f; AND &#x3f;&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;&#xa;&#x29; AS PH &#xd;&#xa;
```

Here is what I tried,

```
sed -e 's/CONVERT_TZ.*&#xd;&#xa/CreatedAt\&#xd;\&#xa/
```

But It is replacing until the last occurrence of `&#xd;&#xa`, i.e., the end of string and coming as,

```
AuthorSessionId&#xd;&#xa;, CreatedAt&#xd;&#xa;
```

as it is replacing until the last occurrence of the `&#xd;&#xa;`.

How to replace only until the first occurrence of string `&#xd;&#xa;`? Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **greedy** issue can be avoided in this particular case by adding `CreatedAt` to search term

```
sed 's/CONVERT_TZ.*CreatedAt&#xd;&#xa/CreatedAt\&#xd;\&#xa/'
# or use back-reference to re-use strings
sed 's/CONVERT_TZ.*\(CreatedAt&#xd;&#xa\)/\1/'
```

In general, you can use **non-greedy** `.*?` if the regex flavor used by command supports it

```
perl -pe 's/CONVERT_TZ.*?&#xd;&#xa/CreatedAt&#xd;&#xa/'
# or lookahead to avoid repeating '&#xd;&#xa'
perl -pe 's/CONVERT_TZ.*?(?=&#xd;&#xa)/CreatedAt/'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your `sed` comment works sleeky for me as this is going to run inside the docker container where we can't sure about perl installation. Can you also please add your `sed` solution with this answer? So that I can accept.